# Location of endpointscfg.py on a Mac

Tags: python, google-cloud-endpoints

I just wrote a Google Cloud Endpoints API using Python (using the latest Mac OS), and now need to create an Android Client by following this:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/endpoints_tool

In the instructions, it says that there's a file called endpointscfg.py under google_appengine, but I can't find them.

When I downloaded the GAE SDK for Mac, I only got a DMG containing GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app.  I placed it under my Applications folder.

Below is the contents of GoogleAppEnglineLauncher.app, with clearly no *.py files.

```
my-macbook-pro:GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app user1$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@   3 user1  admin   102 May 30 10:16 .
drwxrwxr-x+ 124 root    admin  4216 Jul  5 10:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x@   8 user1  admin   272 May 30 10:16 Contents
my-macbook-pro:GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app user1$
```

Where do I find endpointscfg.py?  Thanks.

Gerard

Answer (score 0):

Er, it's in `google_appengine`. You're not looking in `google_appengine`, you're looking GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app.

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) for the Mac SDK explains, when you ran the launcher for the first time, you should have been prompted to let it install the actual code in `/usr/lib/google_appengine`, which is where you'll find everything you need.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I found mine under usr/local/bin.  Actually, it can be executed from anywhere, so it was unnecessary for me to hunt down the path.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's in usr/local/bin

To figure out the path on your Mac, follow these steps:

1. Launch Google App Engine Launcher
2. Go to GoogleAppEngineLauncher menu > Make Symlinks
3. Look for "to be made in" followed by a [path]
4. That [path] is where endpointscfg.py is located